# GPSD and Bluetooth Configuration Ubuntu 16.04 Issue

Tags: bluetooth, gps

GPSD is not working correctly when a bluetooth GPS is connected. This is what happens,  for some reason XGPS does not see data from GPSD, it's random at best when it works, however RFCOMM0 does have data. IF you type GPSMON RFCOMM0, you can see information from the GPS every sec, none stop. However, XGPS does not and if use a mapping software like NAVIT, it gets no data either.

If I disconnect the bluetooth GPS and connect a USB GPS,  Using the config file GPSD in the `/etc/default` location..  where `DEVICES=/dev/rfcomm0` is set to `/dev/GPS0`, `xgps` works and so does NAVIT.

On the previous version of ubuntu , It worked fine with the BLUETOOTH GPS, X160 by Dual, SkyPro.

I have these lines in my rc.local to connect the bluetooth GPS on startup.
(note that also a manual process of connecting the GPS renders the same result)
in my `rc.local`:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth

rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 00:19:01:45:A1:E5 1
```